# CkEditor gives error when using config.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor gem. `https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor`

When I create a file called `config.js` under `assets/javascripts/ckeditor`,

I get following error:

`Cannot call method 'split' of undefined`

The gem gives a minified version and so Im not able to get the exact statement thats causing the issue. but on inspection the following line shows up:

```
a[g].$.styleSheet.cssText=a[g].$.styleSheet.cssText+f:a[g].$.innerHTML=a[g].$.innerHTML+f}}var d={};CKEDITOR.skin={path:b,loadPart:function(c,d){CKEDITOR.skin.name!=CKEDITOR.skinName.split(",")[0]?CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(CKEDITOR.getUrl(b()+"skin.js"),function(){a(c,d)}):a(c,d)},getPath:function(a){return CKEDITOR.getUrl(c(a))},icons:{},addIcon:function(a,b,c){a=a.toLowerCase();this.icons[a]||(this.icons[a]={path:b,offset:c||0})},getIconStyle:function(a,b,c,d){var e;if(a){a=a.toLowerCase();b&&
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
```

If I remove contents of config.js, I get no error.

EDIT:

I used the following generator:

`rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip`

And :( when I press image button I dont get upload button at all. It worked fine before!
What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you need to define [`CKEDITOR.skinName`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-cfg-skinName) in your `config.js` by setting [`config.skin`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-skin).

Hard to say why, but perhaps it's not set to any default value in that gem package. Most likely it should be `moono`.

Comment: Thank yu so much! Made my day :)

Comment: But now I cant see 'browse server' button in image dialog :( :( If I delete config.js it comes back agaain!! :(

Comment: That's a different issue, but caused by the same fact - some default options are not set if config file exists and you need to set them by yourself. E.g. `extraPlugins = 'filebrowser';`.

Comment: The value isnt submitting :(